# Examples of Non-Faithful Group Actions

Tags: group-theory, examples-counterexamples, group-actions

I cannot find anywhere a relatively simple example of a non-faithful group action.

I feel I understand the definition relatively well, however I can't come up with any ideas for one in my head (and despite scouring the internet, the only ones I have seen are for groups which, in my introductory group theory class, we have not covered).

Are there any simple examples that anyone can suggest?

Comment: The most obvious one is a trivial action with $gx=x$ for all $g$ and $x$.

Answer (score 6):

Take any group $H$ acting faithfully on a set $X$ and any noninjective group homomorphism $G\to H$. Then $G$ acts on $X$ as well, but not faithfully.

This may sound contrived, but actually any non-faithful action is of this kind (we can simply let $H$ be $G$ modulo the kernel of the action).

Comment: Take the cyclic group of order 6 (elements {0,1,2,3,4,5} and let it act on the set {even, odd} by ``addition''. I.e. ``even''+3 is odd, ``even''+4 is even, ``odd''+3 is even etc. Then the set {0,2,4} is the kernel.

Comment: @ahulpke That would be $G=\mathbb Z/6\mathbb Z$ projected onto $H=\mathbb Z/6\mathbb Z$ with its action on $X=H$ itself (by left multiplication)

Answer (score 1):

The group $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$ has a natural but nonfaithful action on the projective space $\mathbb{R}P^1$. Letting $M \in SL_2(\mathbb{R})$ and letting $\ell_{\vec v} \in \mathbb{R}P^1$ be the line through the origin with a direction vector $\vec v$, the action is given by 
$$M \cdot \ell_{\vec v} = \ell_{M \vec v}
$$
The kernel of this action is all multiples of the identity matrix $\pmatrix{a&0\\0&a}$.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a technical example. Let us consider the map $\Phi: \mathbb{Z} \times S^1 \longrightarrow S^1$ defined as $\Phi(m, e^{i\theta}) = e^{i\pi m}.e^{i\theta}$, for all $m \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $\theta \in [0, 2\pi]$. One can check this map defines an action of $\mathbb{Z}$ on $S^1$ by multiplication in some manner. This action is not faithful since for all $x \in S^1$, $2\mathbb{Z}$ fixes $x$.

Answer (score 0):

For a concrete example, groups with a non-trivial center acting on their set of subgroups via conjugation work well (in fact, I think Hagen von Eitzen gave you a description of *all* non-faithful group actions).

In the dihedral groups acting on a regular $2n$-gon with $n$ even, the half-rotation is in the center of the group, and fixes every subgroup.

Answer (score 0):

If $\{1\}\ne H\unlhd G$, then the $G$-action $\varphi$ by left multiplication on the quotient group $G/H$ is non-faithful, because:
\begin{alignat}{1}
\ker\varphi &= \bigcap_{g\in G}gHg^{-1}= H\ne\{1\}
\end{alignat}